When $n ≥ 3$, a pattern made by overlapping $n$ circles.

For $n ≥ 3$, a pattern can be made by overlapping $n$
circles, each of circumference $1$ unit, so that each circle
passes through a central point and the resulting pattern
has order-n rotational symmetry.
For instance, the diagram shows the pattern where $n = 7$.
If the total length of visible arcs is $60$ units, what is $n$?

This is the picture:
This question is pretty interesting and I have a quick solution. Although my solution is provided, I would appreciate any additional/further solutions if available.

For anyone curious, here's Mathematica code to reproduce this image: With[{n=7},Show[Graphics[Table[Rotate[Circle[{1,0},1,{-Pi,2Pi/n}],(2 j-1/4)Pi/n,{0,0}],{j,1,n}]]]]. (Changing the value of n will correspondingly adjust the number of overlapping circles.) The arc range of $2\pi/n-(-\pi)=2\pi(1/n+1/2)$ agrees, after rescaling to get unit circumference, with the arc length $1/n+1/2$ per circle found in the answers below.

Let $A$ be the centre of the pattern, then for each circle there
is a centre $O$ and an isosceles triangle $ABC$ as pictured below:
Then:$∠BAC =360/n$
$∠ABC = ∠ACB =(1/2)(180 − (360-n))=90-180/n$
$∠AOC = 2∠ABC = 180 − 360/n$
The reflex angle $AOC$=$180 +360/n$=$360(1/2+1/n)$
Consequently the visible arc is $(1/2+1/n)$ of the circle and it has arc length: $(1/2+1/n)$
The total of all visible arcs is then$n(1/2+1/n)$=$n/2+1$=$60$
So $n/2=59$ and $n=118$
$118$ is the answer.

The visible arc of a single circle must be a half circumference plus twice the angle measure of the inscribed angle whose vertex is the center of the figure, and whose rays pass through the circle's center, or through the other intersection point of the circle with its covering neighbor.  But since this inscribed angle is half the angle between the centers of adjacent circles, it follows that the visible arc has angle measure $\pi + \frac{2\pi}{n}$.  If the circumference is $1$, this means a single visible arc's length is $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}$ and the total length of all $n$ arcs is $\frac{n}{2} + 1$.  For a total length of $60$, $n = 118$.
This reasoning is essentially the same as the solution you wrote.

For a slightly different solution, consider the union of the given figure with its mirror image, so that we have $n$ symmetrically overlapping circles.  Then the total length of this figure is just $n$.
But we can also observe that if $f(n)$ is the total arclength of the original figure, then we must have $$2f(n) - g(n) = n,$$ where $g(n)$ is the total arclength of the figure's boundary, since $2f(n)$ counts the boundary twice.
What is $g(n)$?  Since the angle between successive cusps is $\frac{2\pi}{n}$, again by the inscribed angle theorem, the central angle measure of a single arc along $g$ is twice this, or $\frac{4\pi}{n}$, and its arclength is $\frac{4\pi}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{2\pi} = \frac{2}{n}$.  So $g(n) = 2$ for all $n$.
Therefore, if $f(n) = 60$, we have $$n = 2(60) - 2 = 118.$$
Something interesting about this solution is that we can consider extreme cases of $n$ to reason that $g(n)$ is constant.  When $n = 2$, there are only two circles that do not overlap except at the center so the arclength of the boundary is the sum of two full circumferences; i.e., $2$.  And when $n \to \infty$, the boundary of the figure tends toward a circle with radius twice that of the individual circles, hence has circumference $2$.  Of course, this isn't a proof, but it provides heuristic evidence to support the fact that the boundary always has the same length.

Exercise for the reader:  for any arrangement, not necessarily symmetrical, of $n \ge 2$ congruent circles passing through a single common point, is the boundary of this figure always of constant length?
